# Possible to check mutex is locked before calling pthread_cond_wait()?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'd like to add some debugging code to an abstraction of `pthread_cond_wait` in my code to check that the calling code really holds the mutex, as it should. This is to check correctness of the rest of the callers.

Is there a way to check if the mutex is locked, or enable a debug mode in the pthreads implementation (on Linux) to tell me if it's not?

Comment: If it's not completely obvious that you own the mutex at this point, your code needs serious fixes...

Comment: @R.. For simple cases, fine. As the code grows and becomes more complex, and is worked on over time by different people, less obvious. Verification is preferable to relying on "obvious" correctness.

Comment: If the scope in which a lock is held is so poorly defined that you're not sure whether it's held or not when you get to `pthread_cond_wait`, then the code is almost surely full of deadlocks. In good code, at any particular point where you might call a synchronization primitive, the set of relevant locks you hold should be a static constraint (relative to variable parameters reflecting which objects you're working on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create the mutex as an error-checking mutex, using:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
pthread_mutex_t errchkmutex;

pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
pthread_mutex_init(&errchkmutex, &attr);
```

...then `pthread_cond_wait()` will return `EPERM` if the mutex is not locked by the calling thread.

(of course you would add error-checking to that mutex initialisation code).

I think error-checking mutexes are exactly the kind of "debugging mode" that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_cond_wait` will fail unless the mutex is locked by the calling thread. Are you checking return values of pthread functions?  If not, this is a recipe for disaster, moreso with threading than with other system calls.

Comment: My man page says "pthread_cond_init, pthread_cond_signal, pthread_cond_broadcast, and pthread_cond_wait never return an error code."

Comment: Your manpage is wrong (linux doc has always been crap), or you are running some obscure version of linux that does not implement POSIX semantics. pthread_cond_wait is specified to return EPERM if "The mutex was not owned by the current  thread  at the time of the call."  See, for example, here: http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?pthread_cond_wait+3  (in any case you can make a simple test program.)

Comment: I tested. pthread_cond_wait() works fine and returns 0 if the mutex is not locked by the calling thread, on both my development Linux machine and my embedded Linux target.

Comment: Then you should report a bug to libc and kernel maintainers.

Comment: `EPERM` is only relevant for error-checking mutexes (and perhaps recursive ones but opengroup.org is down at the moment and I don't have a local copy of POSIX handy). For normal mutexes, calling `pthread_cond_wait` without holding the mutex is UB. Thus, if you mention that you need to make the mutex an error-checking one, this answer would exactly solve OP's problem!

Comment: @zvrba: It is not a bug, because [POSIX only requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) the `EPERM` return for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` or robust mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, pieced together from zvrba and "R" and some other research, is to create the mutexes with error-checking attributes and check the return value of `pthread_cond_wait()`.

```
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
```

Other relevant info:

- My glibc requires `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before any includes to enable `pthread_mutexattr_settype()`
- I found I do have the POSIX manpages installed as well as the "LinuxThreads" ones. I'm not sure what (ubuntu) packages the various ones came from, but editing `/etc/manpath.config` to put "`3posix`" first means I get the right ones now.